# When exporting a SSRS report with multiple detail rows to CSV, extra columns are generate for each detail row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report with 3 detail rows

```
                AA BB CC DD
Detail Row 1    A1 B1 C1 D1
Detail Row 2    A2 B2 C2 D2
Detail Row 3    A3 B3 C3 D3
```

When exporting to CSV, I expect to have 4 columns:

```
AA,BB,CC,DD
A1,B1,C1,D1
A2,B2,C2,D2
A3,B3,C3,D3
```

Instead I get:

```
 AA,BB,CC,DD,AA,BB,CC,DD,AA,BB,CC,DD
 A1,B1,C1,D1,A2,B2,C2,D2,A3,B3,C3,D3
```

Any idea how to get these to export to CSV as 4 columns instead of 4 columns x the number of detail rows I have?

Comment: Is this for a table or matrix data region?  You can get a similar output with a matrix, though it is usually transposed from what you have.  AA, A1 on line 1, followed by BB, B1, and so on.

Comment: If you remove the group header on the column group.. does it still do that?

Comment: @JoeS It's a Table

Comment: @Harry Unfortunately, that wouldn't help as we need the column headers on the UI / when exporting to other formats

Comment: @ScottRFrost what I have done in the past is to provide a custom button on the original report that says "Export to CSV". This will export another hidden report differently formatted to suit the extract need as a CSV.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a screenshot of what the table looks like in design mode? I cannot reproduce the same issue when I create a basic table with the same data.

Comment: Scott, did you ever solve this issue? If not, what version of SQL Server are you using? It may be a bug that a newer version fixes.

Comment: @JoeS I never found a fix for it, I ended up having to refactor the report to only use a single detail row and the stored proc just do the grouping / sorting.